# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server

Tags: php, postgresql

My php code is one server and database is different one. In this server to connect 300-500 computer that show error on connection error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server : Cannot assign requested address is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5435

Comment: That be good working with 200 computer but increased number of connection that be throw error.

Even configure the Php and postgres to max number of connection and and all max configure but issue is not solve.

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59650 about what **Cannot assign requested address** means when there are many open connections.

Comment: Thanks Ms. Daniel Vérité  for this solution.

Comment: Ms. Daniel Vérité This is not working in ubuntu 12.04 please any suggestion. we are using server 8 GB RAM with postgresql and optimized postgres as it was earlier in RHEL 5 in same server and our problem was solved with your old suggestion but this is not working in present scenario. please help

Answer (score 8):

if unix (with selinux enabled) then run as root this:

## setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

Comment: What does this code do? Add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Hello, sorry. if you using a unix O.S, open the terminal and run this command as root: 
 setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS 7. `httpd_can_network_connect (HTTPD Service):: Allow HTTPD scripts and modules to connect to the network.`

Comment: For me, also on CentOS 7. I checked using audit2allow to get the missing rules I needed.  
`tail -n 5000 /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow 


#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! WARNING: 'etc_t' is a base type.
allow httpd_t etc_t:dir write;

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using one of the these booleans:
#     httpd_can_network_connect, httpd_can_network_connect_db
allow httpd_t postgresql_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;`